# Command Prompt shows up and disappears immediately

Tags: windows, command-line

When I open Start > Run, type `cmd.exe` and press Enter, a black window shows up and disappears immediately.

- I've tried opening it from `C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe`
- I've tried cleaning the `PATH` environment variable

However none of these have made any difference. Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this problem and solved it in the following way:

Go to the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

It has an `AutoRun` value set to `(Exit)`. Delete this value and the Command Prompt should work again.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue once, and this probably looks like a virus/worm issue. Check if your Task Manager & Registry Editor is disabled?

Comment: Do you mean to check if I can open the Task manager and the Registry editor ? if so, I can open them and they work fine.

Comment: @Nour: Can you try to get a screenshot of Command Prompt just before exiting? Also, which Windows you are running? Also, Can you try running from different user account, maybe Administrator?

Comment: I'm running windows 7 with administrator user and I tried to run as administrator , I  also tried to get a screen shot and there is no error message, just the normal message of the command prompt. (Microsoft Windows Version 6.1.7600) Copyright (C) .....

Comment: @Nour: If your system is really infected, then I don't think that just renaming cmd.exe will work. I had issues with Sysinternal's Process Explorer, the malware used to kill it even when I renamed the EXE. Looked like it was checking the Application Title. Also, If you're getting Command Prompt Version & Copyright in the screenshot, then there must be some other problem.

Comment: @anilmwr could you advise me with some anti-mall-ware programs ?

Comment: @Nour: I am too running Windows 7 32bit. md5 checksum for cmd.exe on my system is 8ae6dd9a6d246004da047f704f0cc487. Check with yours. Also, I don't know how much I can help you with this. I think you should try with a security related forum.

Comment: @anilmwr thank you for your efforts, I'm using windows 7 64bit :) does that make any difference ?

Comment: @Nour: I think it will. md5 checksum for cmd.exe will be different on 32bit & 64bit, I think.

Comment: Ok, anyway I tried to copy the file from another computer with the same operating system, and nothing has changed. I have no choice except to run an anti-mal-ware application.

Answer (score 0):

Go to windows directory (c:\windows\system32), find `cmd.exe` and copy it somewhere (like c:\ or desktop), then rename it to for example `cmd2.exe` and run it. If it works then you are infected with some kind of malware.

Comment: actually it didn't run, and I managed to read the following message:  the system cannot find the text for message number .... in the message file.

Comment: Then don't move the vopy, just create a copy of it with a different name. It is looking for some file in `c:\windows\system32` and cannot find it (message texts are inside that file probably)

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't work .

Answer (score -1):

Try one best solution Copy CMD.exe from some other computer and paste it in your computer.

Comment: :) thanks for answer, but I think I already solved the problem.